# Xcode - change provisioning profile

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile

I want to change provisioning profile for my iOS application.
I did not have apple license before so i was using different Team.

But recently I got my annual developer license with different account.
So I just tried to change it to my new account/Team, but xcode shows

> Failed to create provisioning profile
>
> No profiles for "com.abc.abc" were found

I tried logged into both account and tried to resolve this but i couldn't not found way to do it.

Thank You

Comment: Try changing the Bundle Identifier. And ensure you have ticked Automatically Manage signing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change `Bundle Identifier`

Comment: But I would like to keep Bundle Identifier since it is tied to 3rd party cloud system... Is it possible to change owner of the bundle identifier?

Comment: I face same issue. I change bundle identifier in Xcode Project. In same project, create a new application with new bundle identifier at Firebase.